# How to set pickerView and Keyboard for one textField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

This is my first app. I have two text fields one for selecting Projects and second for selecting Tasks. If I select one project from the 1st text field and its showing related tasks in the 2nd text field. If task array is empty, then I have to show keyboard for entering some text for input to the 2nd text field. Please, someone, guide me how to achieve this task.

[image: I have attached my project image]

Comment: You should just listen for the selection on the first text field and change the inputView depending on what is picked in the first text field.

Comment: Please add some code for how your first text view is working and what you have currently tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let you have two `UITextField` as `firstTextField` and `secondTextField`. Then you can change the input view of `UITextField` as:

```
    if firstTextField.text == "" {
        secondTextField.inputView = nil
    } else {
        secondTextField.inputView = loadPicker()
    }
```

Where,

```
func loadPicker() -> UIPickerView {
    // Load picker and return from here
    return UIPickerView()
}
```

Comment: Note that this code will have to be run in the delegate functions of the firstTextField. In this case it is prob better to set up the picker once and then set it to that picker or nil instead of creating it every time

Comment: Thank you so much.